# Target AJAX id in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My script is this:

```
function comtype($id, $comtype, $vendor){
        //get the input value
        $.ajax({
            //the url to send the data to
            url: "example.com/updatedb.php",
            //the data to send to
            data: {id: $id, comtype: $comtype, vendor: $vendor},
            //type. for eg: GET, POST
            type: "POST",
            //on success
            success: function(data){
                console.log("***********Success***************"); //You can remove here
                console.log(data); //You can remove here
                (function($) {              
                  jQuery.fn.extend({
                    prependClass: function(newClasses) {
                      return this.each(function() {
                        var currentClasses = $(this).prop("class");
                        $(this).removeClass(currentClasses).addClass(newClasses + " " + currentClasses);
                      });
                    }
                  });

                })(jQuery);
                $("#mycontent a.half").removeClass("half").prependClass("paid");
                //$("#mycontent a.pending").removeClass("pending").prependClass("half");

            },
            //on error
            error: function(){
                    console.log("***********Error***************"); //You can remove here
                    console.log(data); //You can remove here
            }
        });
    }
```

For this particular line:

```
$("#mycontent a.half").removeClass("half").prependClass("paid");
```

I want to be able to target the exact class which uses the id.

For example, I have several links with classes such as:

```
class="half first4234"
class="half first8293"
class="half first9221"
```

I have tried the following:

```
$("#mycontent a.half first$id").removeClass("half").prependClass("paid");
```

That throws the following error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #mycontent a.half first$id
```

How can I get the $id and make this work correctly?

Comment: Try using the selector like this: `$("#mycontent a.half first" + $id)`

Comment: It's not targeting the class for some reason.  I also tried removing the spaces $("#mycontent a.half first"+$id) and adding a dot ($("#mycontent a.half .first" + $id)

Comment: That's because the element has both classes. In that case you need to do `$("#mycontent a.half.first" + $id)`

Comment: That's the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the variable into the selector string

```
$("#mycontent a.half first" + $id)
```

Comment: It's not targeting the class for some reason.  I also tried removing the spaces $("#mycontent a.half first"+$id) and adding a dot ($("#mycontent a.half .first" + $id)  The exact link (as it appears in my code) is <a href="#inbound" class="half first3547" onclick="comtype(3547,'inbound', 704)">$184.20</a>  The mycontent id is correct.

Comment: Got it!  $("#mycontent a.half.first"+$id)